# Plot points in between 2 sets of numbers

Tags: excel

Please consider the following data:

```
    -SD            Mean          +SD
A   19.1            28          36.99   
B   7.92           12.6         17.28      
C   14.04          19.7         25.36    
D   10.68          16.1         21.52     
E   7.68           12.4         17.12    
F   7               9.5         12
```

Taking Mean as the base, I have to plot the following points on a chart/graph.

Points: 39, 10, 25, 15, 17, 13.

Something like this:

[image]

Is this possible in Excel? Or any other way I can achieve this requirement?

Comment: How are the points 39, 10, 25, 15, 17, 13 related to the given data? I don't see any logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is a bit off topic for SO (should be asked at Superuser) I'll still give you an idea.

I assume you want something like this:

[image]

At first we need to recalculate the values.

> I assumed multiplicative behavior. If that is not desired, simply change the formula from `=(F2-C2)/(D2-B2)` to `=F2-C2`.

Next to it, you need a descending list of numbers. Now select both of them and hit x/y scatter chart.

By setting fixed max/min values and transparent background you also can pull and resize it over your numbers to look like in your picture. With the set ranges, you now can use "smart art" to add extra lines while there are also other options...

Comment: Many thanks Dirk. This looks promising. Can you upload a copy of your excel file where you have tried it out?

Comment: @IWantToLearn [THIS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_752Ga6Yb7udzVMVWdGNk5UbEk/view?usp=sharing) should do (if you have problems in downloading, pls tell)

Comment: Many thanks. I want to understand why did you need to recalculate values and create the chart and the last column? 

Second, is it possible to build a chart based on the Mean column? I want to achieve the output similar to the one I posted. I even want to show -SD and +SD on the left and right of the Mean column, with the labels, and plot these points keeping the mean column as a base. Just asking if it is possible in excel.

Comment: @IWantToLearn sorry but something like this is simply not possible... excel is not able to work with different scales and ranges in one chart like that. To have it look like this is possible, but you have to use some *cheating* like I have done with the recalculated values. Another way would be the combination of multiple smart arts controlled by VBA (which would be a lot of work to have it variable)

Comment: Thanks again. Can I add two lines for -SD and +SD? You mentioned smart art however I am clueless

Comment: Either add 2 additional graphs with the values of 0.5 and -0.5 for all values, or go to the "insert" tab and look for the small window with the arrows and squares and all that stuff... there are also simple straight lines... just add 2 of them and put them over your chart where 0.5 and -0.5 would be...

Comment: Thanks for the tip Dirk! I followed your advice and posted a follow up question at SuperUser. Can you also look at it please http://superuser.com/questions/1110596/plot-a-value-on-the-chart-based-on-three-values .